# Failure when generating Javascript Swagger client

Tags: javascript, yaml, swagger, swagger-editor

I'm trying to generate a Javascript Swagger client for OpenMBEE's MMS tool by taking the YAML file at https://mms.openmbee.org/alfresco/mms/mms.swagger.yaml and coping it into https://editor.swagger.io/. However, I get an error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (). 
Uncaught (in promise) Error
at http.js:177
at l (runtime.js:63)
```

I can successfully generate clients with this YAML file for other languages (Python or javascipt-closure-angular), but not for Javascript.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you should include your code here instead of linking to other sites.

Comment: It's 1503 lines long

Comment: This is a bug. Open an issue here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues